# kendoRendered triggered multiple times

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui

I have the following code in my Angular controller:

```
$scope.$on("kendoRendered", function(e) {
    console.log('final');
});
```

The result is that `final` is logged three times. It may be due to Kendo elements in directives? I'm looking for a way to have a final instance to know that the UI elements are already loaded and start filling out the data.

**UPDATE**

I use `$state.go (state, params );` (Angular ui-router service) to open the page (that has a related controller). First time I open the page (after refresh) `final` is logged three times, if I close and open the page again, `final` is logged once.

Comment: maybe at the first time there are other things need to be loaded as well, so the 'kendoRendered' will trigger multiple times, if the 'e' you passed in is not null, there maybe some useful info in it to help.  a more specific question and detailed code will be more helpful

Comment: what "other things" could be loaded as well that would make `kendoRendered` be fired more than once? If those are elements in directives, why the behavior is different the first time I open the page?

Comment: I can't be sure what 'other things' are,  as you scribing the 'kendoRendered' event, so anything triggerred that event will log a 'final' in your console. I think if you can have console.log(e) in your code, you may find out something useful in the 'e' object passed in.

Comment: I am facing the similar problem (fired twice). Is there any solution?